# Array-notation decay to pointer-notation - only for function parameters?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, parameters, implicit-conversion

I'm currently learning about how C functions can accept multidimensional arrays, by following the treatment in the book [*C primer plus*, by Stephen Prata (6th edition)](http://catalogue.pearsoned.ca/educator/product/C-Primer-Plus/9780321776402.page).

In the book, the author mentions that function that deal with multidimensional array can be declared as...

> ```
> void somefunction( int (* pt)[4] );
> ```
>
> Alternatively, if (and only if) pt is a formal parameter to a
>   function, you can declare it as follows:
>
> ```
> void somefunction( int pt[][4] );
> ```

I understand that in C, array passed into a function will decay into a pointer to the corresponding type. So `pt` in `int pt[][4]` will decay into `int (* pt)[4]`, which is a pointer to array of 4 `int`s.

But I don't understand why this behavior only happens 'if (and only if) pt is a formal parameter to a function". What does this mean? Why is this the case?

Comment: To nitpick, this isn't what is usually referred to as decay, this is type adjustment.

Comment: So, I +1'ed you, but do pay attention to some of the edits I've made - especially the shortening of the question title. Overly long titles are quite problematic.

Comment: @StoryTeller, thanks for the tip. Using the correct terminology is definitely very important :)

Comment: @einpoklum Thanks for the edit. You have made my question much clear and easier to understand. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: @Thor: Practice by trying to edit other people's posts - which you [should be able to do soon](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think he means that you may not declare an array like this

```
int pt[][4];
```

in a program (except a declaration with external or internal linkage) because it is an incomplete type that is the size of the array is unknown.

However you may use such a declaration as a parameter declaration

```
void somefunction( int pt[][4] );
```

because the parameter is adjusted by the compiler to pointer of the type

```
void somefunction( int ( *pt )[4] );
```

and pointers are always complete types.

As result for example these function declarations

```
void somefunction( int pt[100][4] );
void somefunction( int pt[10][4] );
void somefunction( int pt[][4] );
```

are equivalent and declare the same one function.

Below there is an example of declaring an array (when a declaration is not a definition) of incomplete type with external linkage.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int pt[2][4];

int main(void) 
{
    extern int pt[][4];

    printf( "sizeof( pt ) = %zu\n", sizeof( pt ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
sizeof( pt ) = 32
```

Answer (score 2):

The similar syntax between plain arrays and function parameter arrays is the source of a whole lot of confusion.

If you declare a plain array, you can do so like this:

```
int arr[3] = {1,2,3};
```

or you can do:

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3};
```

These forms are 100% equivalent, the latter simply tells the compiler to to count the number of elements and fill in the `3` for you.

Similarly, you could do this with a 2D array, but only with the left-most dimension:

```
int arr[][3] = { {1,2,3}, {1,2,3} };
```

which is the same as `int arr[2][3]`.

All of the above applies to any plain local or global arrays. Notably, the above only works because there is an initializer list present. Without the initializer list, we can't write `int arr[];` - that's not valid C syntax. So far so good.

---

To create the maximum amount of confusion, C also allows function parameters to be declared as `void func (int arr[3]);` or alternatively `void func (int arr[])`. As it turns out, these two forms are also equivalent. But for an entirely different reason!

Because in the function case specifically, the array declaration always get adjusted ("decay") into a pointer to the first element. So `int arr[3]` when part of a function declaration, is 100% equivalent to `int*`.

When we write `int arr[]` as a function parameter, it is an incomplete type just like when we wrote it with no initializer list above. It cannot be used - it does not mean "function accepting any array size" though in practice that's what will happen. Because the compiler doesn't care about the array size here, since it is a function parameter, which the compiler will replace with a pointer to the first element anyhow. So no matter what we type between the `[ ]` we end up with an `int*`.

The rule of array decay applies to any parameter type. So if you use a 2D array, which is really an array of arrays, it decays into a pointer of the first element. Which is the same as a pointer to the first array. So you can write `int pt[][4]` and it will work. So will `int pt[666][4]`. You end up with `int (*)[4]` no matter.

But this rule of array decay does not apply "recursively": the C compiler only sees a single array. It happens to be an array of arrays, but the compiler doesn't care. So we can't write `int arr[][]`, because that would result in `int (*)[]` which is an array pointer to an incomplete type, which isn't allowed as a function parameter.